# Diophantine Equation. Prove that it only have one set of equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

I have this equation  $25x - 35y = 40$. I have found a set of solution for it. How do I prove that it only has one set of solution?
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is this "set of solution" that you have found?

Answer (score 2):

It's $$5x-7y=8$$ or
$$5(x-y)-2y=8.$$
Let $x-y=t$.

Thus, $$5t-2y=8$$ or
$$t+2(2t-y)=8.$$
Let $2t-y=-m$, where $m\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus, $$t=2m+8,$$
which gives $$y=5m+16$$ and $$x=7m+24$$ or
$$y=5(m+3)+1$$ and
$$x=7(m+3)+3$$ and we got the answer:
$$\{(7m+3,5m+1)|m\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the given diophantine equation is equivalent to $5x - 7y = 8$. One "easy" solution is $(3,1)$. Let $(x,y)$ be another solution, then
$$5(x-3)=7(y-1)$$
and since $\gcd(5,7)=1$, it follows that $y-1=5k$ and $x-3=7k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, it is straightforward to verify that $(7k+3,5k+1)$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a solution of $5x - 7y = 8$.

Therefore, the whole set of solutions is $\{(7k+3,5k+1):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for linear diophantine eq such as 
                         ax + by = c
exist only if gcd (a,b)  divides c. (all letters stand for integers)

Then the solutions are given by

```
   x= r + (b/gcd(a,b))t       and  y= s -  (a/gcd(a,b))t
```

where r and s are any specific (integer) solution , in this case r=3, s=1,
and t is any integer.